# How to add incremental numbers to the end of a filename when saving in asp.net web forms c# application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The code below is supposed to rename a file with numbers if another file with the same name already exists.  For example, test.docx, test(2).docx, etc...  It works just fine on my localhost, but when I put it on the web server it changes the file name to test.docx(2).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here's what I'm currently using:

```
protected void btn_submit_new_doc_vsn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        string filename = fu_new_doc_vsn.FileName;
        if (fu_new_doc_vsn.HasFile)
        {
            while (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Data/") + filename))
            {
                i++;
                filename = fu_new_doc_vsn.FileName + " (" + i.ToString() + ")";
            }
            fu_new_doc_vsn.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Data/") + filename);
        }

        doc_path_text.Text = (Server.MapPath("~/Data/") + filename);

        SqlConnection idrf_cnxn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SRVER\\MYDB;Initial Catalog=idrf;Integrated Security=True");
        {
            SqlCommand new_doc_cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into tbl_doc(doc_title, doc_type_list, doc_org_list, doc_dept_list, doc_desc, prior_contract_cd, legal_comp_contract_id, doc_upld_dt, doc_path, crnt_doc_stat_list, vendor_id_fk) Values(LTRIM(RTRIM(@doc_title)), LTRIM(RTRIM(@doc_type_list)), LTRIM(RTRIM(@doc_org_list)), LTRIM(RTRIM(@doc_dept_list)), LTRIM(RTRIM(@doc_desc)), LTRIM(RTRIM(@prior_contract_cd)), LTRIM(RTRIM(@legal_comp_contract_id)), LTRIM(RTRIM(@doc_upld_dt)), LTRIM(RTRIM(@doc_path)), LTRIM(RTRIM(@crnt_doc_stat_list)), LTRIM(RTRIM(@vendor_id_fk)))", idrf_cnxn);
            new_doc_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doc_title", doc_title_text.Text);
            new_doc_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doc_type_list", doc_type_text.Text);
            new_doc_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doc_org_list", doc_org_list_text.Text);
            new_doc_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doc_dept_list", doc_dept_list_text.Text);
            new_doc_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doc_desc", doc_desc_text.Text);
            new_doc_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prior_contract_cd", prior_contract_cd_text.Text);
            new_doc_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@legal_comp_contract_id", legal_comp_contract_id_text.Text);
            new_doc_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doc_upld_dt", doc_upld_dt_text.Text);
            new_doc_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doc_path", doc_path_text.Text);
            new_doc_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@crnt_doc_stat_list", crnt_doc_stat_list_text.Text);
            new_doc_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vendor_id_fk", vendor_id_fk_text.Text);

            idrf_cnxn.Open();
            new_doc_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            idrf_cnxn.Close();

            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using VS2013, framework is 4.5.1, this is an asp.net web forms application.

Thanks,
J

Comment: try looking up how to use the `string.Format` function

Comment: Locally it is handled out of what the code is doing, maybe to permissions, but if I am reading your code correctly, I think the expected outcome is doc(2) by how you are building the file name. you are appending your created logic to (FileName).

Comment: I think yo may want to use the proprty in IO (Name) and then append your built string, then add the extension. If tat doesnt make sense, I can give you a snippet. See FileName technically returns the name and extensions and on that line, you are taking the name and extension, and just adding your made counter to the very end.

Comment: Casey, that makes sense.  I would appreciate a snippet.

Comment: I just made an answer for you. That is why the File.Exists works, and if it was only the name and know extension on that check, it would return false every time. Looking for test instead of test.txt. When these things happens, and it seems to not make sense at all why something is happening, debug and put a watch on the variable. You would of seen it right away. Hope it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it should be somthing like this, if you read my prior comment:

```
int i = 0;
    string filename = fu_new_doc_vsn.FileName;
    if (fu_new_doc_vsn.HasFile)
    {
        while (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Data/") + filename))
        {
            i++;
            filename = fu_new_doc_vsn.Name + " (" + i.ToString() + ")" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fu_new_doc_vsn.FileName);
        }
        fu_new_doc_vsn.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Data/") + filename);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Casey.  I'm getting an error with "Name".  Any idea what I may be doing incorrectly?  The error is fu_new_doc_vsn doesn't contain a definition for Name.  It states I may be missing a directive or assembly reference?  I have using.System.IO;.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I thought that was an IO object, but do not see what it is defined as in your code example. Where is that coming from, then I can help you.

Comment: Casey - thanks for all of your help.  Your feedback put me on the track to write it a little differently.  I'm not sure where "Name" came from.  I fixed the code my using your advice above..."append your built string, then add the extension".

Comment: Well, in the namespace for System.IO there are different ways to get file information. I shorthanded the method, and my appologies. If you use the Path.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(your file here), it returns only the name property of the file without the extensions. I see your using it, and that is what I meant. I just have used a custom extension for ever, so I can just cal an IO file object like such (file.Name) to return it. Sorry for mixing up the method name on that fr you, but glad it pointed you to the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code...

```
int i = 0;
        string filename = fu_new_doc_vsn.FileName;
        string fnnnoext = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fu_new_doc_vsn.FileName);
        string fnnextonly = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fu_new_doc_vsn.FileName);
        if (fu_new_doc_vsn.HasFile)
        {
            while (System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Data/") + filename))
            {
                i++;
                filename = (fnnnoext + "(" + i.ToString() + ")" + fnnextonly);
            }
            fu_new_doc_vsn.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Data/") + filename);
        }

        hdn_doc_path_text.Value = (Server.MapPath("~/Data/") + filename);
```